# When will it become active on admob at Android app

Tags: android, admob

I made Android app which integrate admob.
Then I run this app on my test device and it show ad banner on the screen. 
But ad's status is still inactive. It makes me confuse.

Do you know that when admob become active?  Run this app  which download from market store?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running test ads or real ads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AdMob statistics are not realtime. It may take a few hours to see your requests on the admob site.