# Is there a way to test Admob without updating my app to the Play Store?

Tags: android, admob

I only have this simple question. I would like to try it before submitting my app. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will it become active on admob at Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990512/when-will-it-become-active-on-admob-at-android-app)

Comment: ShaneQful's link is good, wait a few hours before your ads become active